# What was your very first complete document done with TeX/LaTeX & friends?

Tags: typography, big-list, examples, fun

Recently I looked up my first ever document done with `LaTeX`, and as strange and crazy as it may seems, it was my first thesis (wrote in only two weeks). It all turned out well as I did a very good impression, but this left me with a question that can be posted to the "newcomer"s and the "guru"s out there.

*What was your first complete document wrote in any typesetting language related to `TeX`?*

I'm not talking about the very first test document, but a complete and "beautifully typeset" document that you were able to write; and your impression of it back in the days.

Maybe people like [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) or [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) would refer to their first experience with pure `LaTeX` and even plain `TeX`, as well as other people that came in contact with this program may remember their first impression of their first work.

I've put it inside fun, but I hope I didn't go too off-topic because this is something that came not only to my curiosity, but an opportunity to share the point to *where all it started in the first place*...

Comment: The reference to age should be worthy a downvote. `;-)`

Comment: I'm wondering if I should give -1 for publicly stating that @egreg and I are old:-)

Comment: Hehe...Those two names came first to my mind after the word "LaTeX guru".

Comment: *How did you feel so after realizing the power of this program?* That's an opinion-based question and should get closed.

Comment: @Jubobs First, my apologies; my intention was related on explanation of the first question, the second came after, so if I delete the 2nd (which I didn't need this in the first place), can the downvote be evaded?

Comment: In that connection, I'm also a little sick of always seeing the word "beautiful" every time someone wants to talk about LaTeX. There's nothing "beautiful" about it. You can make a LaTeX document absolutely hideous, and you can make an MS Word document into a visual treat. It's all up to you.

Comment: @Sverre Aw... The "beautiful" is not a personal judgement, but only a quote from the introductory text from `MikTeX` (The `R.J.Drofnats` story) just to remember the "fun". And second: this word appears once in this question so why being upset?

Comment: Why the down vote? Really strange. Though IMHO it may be moved to meta.

Comment: @AndreaL. I'm not upset. My comment was more of a comment to the comment ("In that connection"). We're allowed to have our pet topics. One of mine is the constant mentioning of LaTeX being "beautiful" and Word being "ugly".

Comment: Voting to close: this question has only a purely social value (allowing people to tell personal anecdotes). It adds no value to the site.

Comment: @MMA Meta is for questions about the site, so it doesn't belong there (either).

Comment: I just knew that implicitly (rather than explicitly) mentioning someone old is a taboo here.

Comment: Hi Andrea L.: I think your question suits  **[TeX Community Polls](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1564/15717)** format at meta: Post as answer: **What's your first full TeX/LaTeX document ?** with **multiple options(full thesis/book/..) as comments** to make others upvote

Comment: @texenthusiast thanks for the suggestion, but after moving on meta what will be the "fate" of the question on this site?

Comment: @AndreaL. Your choice whatever you want +what community wants (to be closed/deleted etc..)

Comment: @texenthusiast Thanks, now it has been "migrated" as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

TeX related stuff have been lost in the mist of time were circa 1983-1989, as well as some Technical Reports and local papers. Circa May 1990 [paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=747985&sortType=asc_p_Sequence&filter=AND%28p_IS_Number:16147%29&rowsPerPage=75). PhD Thesis from memory about two years earlier. MSc thesis circa 85. Never touched the PhD stuff after graduation but TeX/LaTeX stayed ingrained in my veins.

Most of the early stuff typed on an Olivetti Computer and then starved to buy an [HP9816](http://www.hpmuseum.net/display_item.php?hw=4). The little circular knob on the left top was a precursor to the mouse, but just scrolled the screen. It came with the incredible memory of 128K RAM.

Answer (score 1):

After some test documents while studying my Bachelor-Thesis was the first really complete document. It was a kind of "must not fail" document but it felt good. Even if I had only less experience I saw that the documet looks much better than everythig else done by MS Word or OpenOffice before.

Comment: The same happened to my thesis, as the "must not fail" kept me awake the nights...

Comment: Yes and for every little error I was searching and searching but the find a solution, even a simple one, was a good feeling.

Answer (score 1):

My first LaTeX document was a paper submission to the Nordic Journal of Linguistics in December 2011 (published in Oct 2012, http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0332586512000194). My preamble then was 21 lines. The last document I wrote (a four-page letter a few days ago) had a preamble of 364 lines, plus it loads a `.sty` file I made with 207 lines of my own macros ...

My first document was also the only scholarly document I wrote with LaTeX and BibTeX in MikTeX. Following a temporary return to MS Word, I started using XeLaTeX and biblatex with TeX Live around July 2012.